# Is there a desktop notification that stays shown until I click it?

Tags: notifications

`notify-send` keeps showing notification for a few second. its option `-t`  specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the notification.

Can I send a notification which will last until I tell it to end, e.g. by clicking it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, if you use `notify-send -u critical -t 0` the notification will stay on the screen until you click it.

It's unfortunate that the man page doesn't mention this.

Comment: `notify-send -t 0` didn't work for me (on Linux Mint 18.2): it disappeared after about 4 seconds.  However, if it's an important error message, then `notify-send -u CRITICAL` works (it has an appropriate icon for an error) and does keep it on the screen.

Comment: @RichardWiseman: Yes, I see the same behavior on Ubuntu 14.04, and I've been using `-u critical` myself. (Apparently the argument is case-insensitive, but the man page refers to `critical`, not `CRITICAL`, so that's what I use.)

Comment: My `man` page also uses lowercase but either case works for me.  In fact, random case works for me too, e.g. `cRiTiCaL`!